# Adding time slice in a matlab output using fprintf

Tags: matlab

I have matlab output of a complex number, where 'modTrace' contains the complex numbers. to write my output in a file called '3pt.txt' I write the following:

```
modTrace
fileID = fopen('3pt.txt','w');
fprintf ( fileID,'%e+%ei\n',real ( traces ), imag ( traces ) );
fclose(fileID);
```

The output looks like this:

```
2.355387e-13+3.263411e-12i
3.037095e-12+1.848502e-12i
2.264321e-12+1.408536e-12i
3.808791e-13-1.647224e-14i
-3.249665e-14+7.954636e-15i
7.026766e-14+1.056313e-13i
```

and so on. Now if I want the output with time slice numbers to the left, something like:

```
0 2.355387e-13+3.263411e-12i
1 3.037095e-12+1.848502e-12i
2 2.264321e-12+1.408536e-12i
3 3.808791e-13-1.647224e-14i
4 -3.249665e-14+7.954636e-15i
5 7.026766e-14+1.056313e-13i
```

and so on, how to I edit the code? 
Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fprintf` statement is not working the way you are intending. It prints out all the values in `real(traces)` before getting to `imag(traces)`. For example,

```
>> v = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]
v =
     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
>> fprintf('%d %d\n',v(:,1),v(:,2))
1 3
5 2
4 6
```

To pair values the way intended, you need to transpose the matrix:

```
>> fprintf('%d %d\n',v.')
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Following this example, you can prepend slice numbers as follows:

```
v = [(1:numel(traces)).' real(traces(:)) imag(traces(:))].';
fprintf(fileID,'%d %e+%ei\n',v)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I didn't realize that my code was printing wrong numbers. Your code was very helpful